# How to display different values of the same column in plot graph/chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The column class has 2 options for the value, either 'b' or 's'. I am trying to display a graph/chart that shows how many are 'b' and how many are 's'. I can't figure out how to do this when they are both in the same column.

The current code shows a scatter plot, but I'd like to use the data from column 'class'.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

#df = df.groupby('class')['class'].count()
#print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df['class'] = ['Benign','Malware','Benign','Malware','Malware']

# plot groupby results on the same canvas 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

for n, grp in df.groupby('class'):
    ax.scatter(x = "x", y = "y", data=grp, label=n)
ax.legend(title="Label")

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by how many are 'b' and how many are 's'?

Comment: The data has a column named 'class' the values in this column are either 'b' or 's'. I'm trying to show how many entries are 'b' and how many are 's' from only that column

Answer (score 3):

Don't group by class and loop, rather aggregate (with `value_counts`) then plot:

```
df['class'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

or with matplotlib's functions:

```
s = df['class'].value_counts()
ax.bar(s.index, s)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks